# Google indicates that it has "omitted some entries very similar"

Tags: seo, google, duplicate-content

I just went to http://www.virante.com/ and entered my website and I encountered this warning:

> Google indicates that it has "omitted some entries very similar" to
>   the top 1000 pages on your site. This similarity may be a duplicate
>   content penalty preventing these pages from being considered uniquely
>   valuable in Google's index

What exactly this message means? (instead of just simple line answer that my site has duplicate content)

Comment: Can you clarify what part of the message is unclear to you?

Comment: What exactly this signifies "Google indicates that it has "omitted some entries very similar" to the top 1000 pages on your site. "?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think it in a dumb user point of view. It's more easy to understand the message "similar pages" or the message "this website has different urls that redirect to the same content that in our point of view is a bad practice"?

Obviously the first.